# sys.argv is not taking provided argument in python 3

Tags: python, command-line

I'm using python 3.3.0 in windows 8.

This is the code which I'm trying to deal with:-

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg == "-u":
        url = sys.argv[2]
        print (url)
        sys.exit(1)
```

So, When I run my program in cmd like:

```
python my.py -u http://www.aytelecom.ae/news-details.php?id=5&type=2
```

I'm getting only `'http://www.aytelecom.ae/news-details.php?id=5`' as my `sys.argv[2]` or in `url` variable!

So, can anybody tell me that why it's skipping `'&type=2'`?
Am I doing mistake anywhere or what's wrong with python 3?

Comment: you could use `sys.argv.index("-u")`

Comment: Hmn, I didn't get you. Would you please elaborate it?

Comment: seq.index(x) returns the index of the first occurrence of x in seq or raises ValueError if x is not in seq. You could use it instead of the for-loop.

Comment: Yup, I got your point but I think it would be useful for only one parameter. What if I have more options to check for?

And when I tried to run this:

    import sys
    sys.argv.index("-u")
    url = sys.argv[2]
    print ("URL:", url)
    sys.exit(1)

It gives something in the last line like:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: if you have more parameters you could use argparse module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

& is a metacharacter in shell. Put the url in quotes.

Comment: oh my god, it was so easy and I have wasted whole day on Google to get a solution! Anyway, Thanks for your quick response. It's really a nice site.